# Move control either horizontally or vertically, not combination of both

Tags: c#, winforms

I was here burning the midnight oil around some lines of code trying to solve a problem.

The code bellow will setup the control to be able to move anywhere within its parent control.

However this code allows to move in any direction, I would like to restrict its movement to either the X or Y axis, meaning either the user can move it horizontally or vertically, never a combination of both.

```
Point lastPosition = Point.Empty;

control.MouseDown += (sender, evt) =>
{
   lastPosition = evt.Location;
};

control.MouseMove += (sender, evt) =>
{
   // This moves the control anywhere.
   // I only want to move in one direction (left<->right  or  top <-> down) never diagonally
   // Not sure how to first find which direction the user wants to move, 
   // nor how to restrict the movement to only one of the directions mentioned
   int x = last.X + movingPiece.Left - mouseDownLocation.X;
   int y = last.Y + movingPiece.Top - mouseDownLocation.Y;
   movingPiece.Left = x;
   movingPiece.Top = y;
};
```

**Thanks**

My thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25591801/114298) and [TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25590312/114298) for their answers, from which I extracted the ideas from which I built a small 2D engine, capable of delimiting areas on where a number of controls can be moved about inside a panel container, taking into account collision detection, prevention and control movement direction constraints imposed by a number of custom factors as required. I would like to accept both answers, but since this isn't possible, I accepted the answer who provided the most insight into the matter in question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @xxbbcc For clarification I edited and provided sample code and my goal in it. Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Well, the 1st step to a solution will be for __you__ to decide on __which__ movement should happen!

Comment: @TaW "Not sure how to first find which direction the user wants to move."

Comment: Well if you don't know, how can we? Maybe the direction shall be decided upon at the start of the movement by checking in which direction the mouse was moved further. You wil have to use a flag to store that direction and probably should use a 2nd flag to remember that the control is moving at all. Remember: There is no shame in using a flag. Or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. I add a scripted small `Panel` 'piece' to a larger `Panel` 'board'.

I check for a minimum delta, so that a shaky hand won't start the movement..

One flag tracks the movement, another one the direction, with '0' being 'not yet' decided.

```
bool pieceMoving = false;
byte pieceDirection = 0;
Point startPosition = Point.Empty;

private void AddPieceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel newPiece = new Panel();
    newPiece.Size = new Size(16, 16);
    newPiece.BackColor = Color.Blue;

    pan_board.Controls.Add(newPiece);

    newPiece.MouseDown += (sender2, evt) => 
           { pieceMoving = true;  pieceDirection = 0; startPosition = evt.Location; };
    newPiece.MouseUp += (sender2, evt) => 
           { pieceMoving = false; pieceDirection = 0;};
    newPiece.MouseMove += (sender2, evt) =>
    {
        int delta = 0;
        if (!pieceMoving) return;
        if (pieceDirection == 0)
        {
            int deltaX = Math.Abs(startPosition.X - evt.X);
            int deltaY = Math.Abs(startPosition.Y - evt.Y);
            delta = deltaX + deltaY;
            if (deltaX == deltaY) return;
            if (delta  < 6) return;  // some minimum movement value
            if (deltaX > deltaY) pieceDirection = 1; else pieceDirection = 2;
        }   
        // else if (delta == 0) { pieceDirection = 0; return; }  // if you like!
        Panel piece = (Panel) sender2;
        if (pieceDirection == 1) piece.Left += evt.X; else piece.Top += evt.Y;

    };
```

Since I have put the code in a `Button` click, I named the sender 'sender2' and I use it to allow for the same code being used for many pieces.

Comment: I've done similar to this in wpf - the only change I would make would be to test the movement reaches a minimum amount before committing. I found that a slight vertical movement is quite common when moving horizontally, so set a boundary of around 10px. Once movement goes beyond that range it gets locked and the other axis reset to zero.

Comment: Quite right, which is why I have added the line above. My hand is so calm I get away with 6 pixels ;-)

Comment: what's more, `pieceDirection` never gets back to 0, so the panel won't be able to move to another direction other than the first direction.

Comment: No, delta is Abs, so it has lost the sign and the code works fine here as it is. pieceDirection is reset in the mousedown and mouseup.

Comment: piece Direction should not only be reset in mousedown or mouseup, but also in mousemove, otherwise the panel cannot be dragged to other direction when the user is still pressing the mouse.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He doesn't want the control to be moved diagonally, but something like projection: only horizontal shift or vertical shift is allowed, but the control still can be moved to **any position** while the mouse is pressing down.

Comment: @nevets : Maybe so, maybe not. I thought of a rook's movement. I suggest to leave that to the OP. But to make you happy I have added a line of code in a comment (**) to allow for that kind of movement. Not sure if that is what is actually what the OP wants. For a chess game it would be wrong.

Comment: The control moves horizontally or vertically and never diagonally. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make this reliable as intended.  The common solution for this UI problem is to provide the user with an assist that he can turn on and off as desired.  The Shift key is the common choice for that.  Allow free movement when it is turned off, but snap in the dominant direction when it is held down.

You use the Control.ModifierKeys property to check if the key is down in your MouseMove event handler.  You need the KeyDown and KeyUp event handlers so you can see the Shift key being pressed and released.  Significant changes are required to properly follow the mouse position, it is not necessarily hovering over the control anymore when you hold down the Shift key.  Enough moving parts to encapsulate this in a helper class:

```
class ControlMover {
    private Control control;
    private Point downPos;
    private Point startPos;
    enum Constrains { None, Hor, Ver };
    private Constrains constraint;

    public ControlMover(Control ctl) {
        control = ctl;
        startPos = control.Location;
        downPos = Cursor.Position;
        control.Capture = true;
        control.MouseMove += control_MouseMove;
        control.MouseUp += control_MouseUp;
        control.MouseCaptureChanged += control_MouseCaptureChanged;
        control.KeyDown += control_KeyDown;
        control.KeyUp += control_KeyUp;
    }

    void handleKey(Keys key, bool down) {
        Console.WriteLine((int)key);
        if (key == Keys.Escape) {
            control.Capture = false;
            control.Location = startPos;
        }
        else if ((key & Keys.KeyCode) == Keys.ShiftKey) {
            if (!down) constraint = Constrains.None;
            else if (constraint == Constrains.None) {
                var curPos = Cursor.Position;
                if (Math.Abs(curPos.X - downPos.X) >= Math.Abs(curPos.Y - downPos.Y))
                     constraint = Constrains.Hor;
                else constraint = Constrains.Ver;
            }
            moveControl();
        }
    }

    void control_MouseCaptureChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // This ends it
        if (control.Capture) return;
        control.MouseMove -= control_MouseMove;
        control.MouseUp -= control_MouseUp;
        control.MouseCaptureChanged -= control_MouseCaptureChanged;
        control.KeyDown -= control_KeyDown;
        control.KeyUp -= control_KeyUp;

    }
    private void moveControl() {
        var curPos = Cursor.Position;
        if (constraint == Constrains.Hor) curPos.Y = downPos.Y;
        if (constraint == Constrains.Ver) curPos.X = downPos.X;
        curPos = control.Parent.PointToClient(curPos);
        // Keep it inside the parent
        curPos.X = Math.Max(0, curPos.X);
        curPos.Y = Math.Max(0, curPos.Y);
        curPos.X = Math.Min(control.Parent.ClientSize.Width - control.Width, curPos.X);
        curPos.Y = Math.Min(control.Parent.ClientSize.Height - control.Height, curPos.Y);
        control.Location = curPos;
    }

    void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { control.Capture = false; }
    void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { moveControl(); }
    void control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { handleKey(e.KeyData, true); }
    void control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { handleKey(e.KeyData, false); }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        new ControlMover(button1);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately keyboard input is not possible for this application. However the code provided insights into coding areas of the application being developed. Thank you.