# Moving control in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, mousemove

I'm with a problem moving a label on a panel. When I move this label, reached the top and left (0.0), the label respects the top and left. To spend half of the screen, the label exceeds the panel as shown in picture.

[image]

My codes:

```
public partial class frmStandard : Form
{
    Point startposition;    
}

public void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    startposition = e.Location;
}

public void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
    {   
        ((Label)sender).Left = Math.Max(0, e.X + ((Label)sender).Left - startposition.X);
        ((Label)sender).Top = Math.Max(0, e.Y + ((Label)sender).Top - startposition.Y);
    }
}
```

I need the label does not exceed the panel size.What should be added in the codes?

Comment: It is probably a Z-order problem, the label disappears underneath that toolbar.  A simple workaround is to *not* put the toolbar on the panel.  The MouseMove code needs work as well, once the Max() does its job then the mouse position gets out of sync with the label position.  Avoid trouble with PointToScreen.  Sample code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25591801/17034).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the other Borders.

You will have to use the dimension data of the containing `Panel` for this.

In the spirit of keeping things dynamic, as your code already is, I use he `Label`'s `Parent` instead of referring to just the one `Panel`:

```
private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Label L = (Label)sender;
  Rectangle PR = L.Parent.ClientRectangle;

  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
     L.Left = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, e.X + L.Left - startposition.X), PR.Right - L.Width);
     L.Top = Math.Min( Math.Max(0, e.Y + L.Top - startposition.Y), PR.Bottom - L.Height);
  }
}
```

To keep it even more general, one could replace `Label` with `Control` and let the user move other `Controls` around wit the same pieces of code..